# Find correct ACPI drivers without trial-and-error

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, acpi

My system is running on a minimal kernel config (based on `make defconfig`).

Now I'm trying to figure out which extra acpi device drivers I have to enable to get everything on my system working. To find a matching driver I could enable it, build & restart, observe dmesg. This is a tedious and error-prone process, and I'd like to be able to choose the correct drivers based on system information.

For PCI or USB devices I was able to utilize `lspci -nn` and searched for the `vendorId:deviceId` in [LKDDb](https://cateee.net/lkddb/).

I have seen ACPI entrys in this database too, but cannot figure out how to extract ACPI device information from my system.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to dump and decompile the `ACPI DSDT` (Differentiated System Description Table) from the BIOS. This includes code for ACPI device initialization specific to the used system, and therefore also includes the necessary device ids.

Decompile the DSDT with the following commands (`iasl` must be installed)

```
cp /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT dsdt.dat
iasl -d dsdt.dat
```

Then query the decompiled code for device ids

```
grep '_HID.*"' dsdt.dsl
```

The output will include all lines where a device is declared, and the respective device ids. Finally utilize `LKDDb` to find the necessary kernel acpi drivers for the devices.

For a quick extraction of the relevant lines you can use this:

```
wget https://cateee.net/sources/lkddb/lkddb.list
for i in $(grep '_HID.*"' dsdt.dsl | grep -o '"[A-Z0-9]*"'); do grep "$i" lkddb.list; done | sort -u > relevant
```

Furthermore list all `CONFIG_*` variables from the output:

```
cat relevant | grep -o 'CONFIG[A-Z0-9_]*' | sort -u
```

Note that this list is only a guidance, and does not guarantee to be free of false positives or false negatives. If you want to be sure about what you are doing, you should investigate the `dsdt.dsl` yourself.